# Status Code (Result Code) in Azure Function Timer Trigger + NodeJs

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I want to ask that - how to set status code (result/response code) in timer trigger azure function, if any failure occurs.

Ex- If any error occur due to bad input, than I want to throw an error with status code as 400. And than further this will logged as 400 result code. Currently it's only throwing the Exception and Stack, also logging with same. Now  I want additional field status code (result code/response code) with these exception and stack.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

status code only works for http trigger, throwing an exception is the right way for the time trigger

Comment: I want to capture the status code with Time Trigger, or any other trigger. Is there any possible way or any workaround to achieve this, for my function capturing status (result/response) code  very important for monitoring. I went through the below link but not found any solution for node perspective :- [link](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/3114). Please share the code if you have anything.

Comment: as I said, status code is only for HTTP Trigger. You'll need to change / rewrite your function using http trigger

Answer (score 0):

In general, the return value of a timer trigger is ignored, so not much is achieved by returning anything from function. You can either

1. throw an exception (with appropriate error message and chained exceptions to provide root cause) OR
2. not throw an exception

If you go with #1 then the exception and stack trace etc would be part of the logs, function invocation would be marked as "failed" and retries would be triggered if configured (specific to trigger type).

For monitoring you can use [App Insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/app-insights-overview) or other features of [App Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/overview). You can report your [custom metrics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-custom-events-metrics) with "status code" and create graphs, reports, alerts etc on top.

If you don't like the App Insights or use some existing APM tool like App Dynamics, Data Dog, Splunk etc then you'll have to push your logs/metrics using appropriate interface the tool provides.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, you can have another function which status specific http status code as per your implementation and result, however timer function should have only one job to trigger that new function.

In this case, you will put your monitoring and analytics logic on the http status code of newly created function.